# import keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer in Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, keras

Which Python package should I install in Intellij to import keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer?

I tried to install keras, keras-preprocessing, neptune-tensorflow-keras, keras-applications, and tensorflow-keras-lite, but it doesn't recognize .text...

[image: error]